How can I show only one color channel as greyscale?
On a web application, I have an img tag showing the output of a camera (streams via websocket, but it's not relevant for the scope of this question).
The img shows color data, but I need my users to be able to view the RED / GREEN / BLUE channels separately. At least, I need my users to select if they are going to see color or R/G/B channels.
I can do this using canvas, but I'm not aware of a simple way to perform this, without extracting the RGB values as uint8 array and processing them. Besides, at the moment I don't have a canvas at all, and the img tag has performed flawlessly for my needs up until now.
I was wondering if there is some CSS magic to show the channels, something like filter/greyscale, but greyscale has a fixed conversion that doesnt allow preserving the channels, as far as I can tell.
I have seen the existence of mix-blend-mode, but that doesn't seem to support my use case neither.
Suggestions?
Given the requests for clarification: extracting the Green channel and showing it as a greyscale means that, if I have a pixel in the original image that is full green (#00FF00) I would like it to show up as perfect white (#FFFFFF).
Similarly, if I select the blue channel, a pixel perfectly blue (#0000FF) should become white (#FFFFFF).
Doing greyscale usually performs a weighted blend of channels, so full green (255) becomes something like 190, but full blue becomes a dark shade of grey (say, 30ish).
The precise numbers are not a concern, the problem is to perform a greyscale in such a way that 255 in the selected channel becomes white.

I'm not certain I fully understand what you want to achieve. Could you explain what it is in the mix-blend-mode example you have linked to that does not meet your requirement?

It must be remembered that CSS is used for styling elements. It's not used for extracting data.

@Rob I don't need to extract data. I need to show the Red, green or blue image channel. It could be a matter of styling.

@AHaworth See my edit, I hope it clears up the scenario.

Please don't tag your titles, and please don't denote edits. That's just clutter for future readers, and they're all in the revision history anyway.

You might use SVG filters:


figure {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em; margin: .2em;
  border: solid 1px;
}

img {
  width: 150px
}

.red {
  filter: url(#red)
}

.green {
  filter: url(#green)
}

.blue {
  filter: url(#blue)
}
<figure>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/RGB_color_wheel_10.svg/250px-RGB_color_wheel_10.svg.png">
  <figcaption>all</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <img class="red" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/RGB_color_wheel_10.svg/250px-RGB_color_wheel_10.svg.png">
  <figcaption>red</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <img class="green" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/RGB_color_wheel_10.svg/250px-RGB_color_wheel_10.svg.png">
  <figcaption>green</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <img class="blue" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/RGB_color_wheel_10.svg/250px-RGB_color_wheel_10.svg.png">
  <figcaption>blue</figcaption>
</figure>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="red">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic"
        type="matrix"
        values="1 0 0 0 0
                1 0 0 0 0
                1 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0"
        result="color" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="green">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic"
        type="matrix"
        values="0 1 0 0 0
                0 1 0 0 0
                0 1 0 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0"
        result="color" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="blue">
      <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic"
        type="matrix"
        values="0 0 1 0 0
                0 0 1 0 0
                0 0 1 0 0
                0 0 1 1 0"
        result="color" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>




This is exactly what I hoped existed. I even saw it in the docs, but did not understand that I could use SVG filters via the url() syntax: I thought it was limited to SVG elements. Thank you!

Have you tried mix-blend-mode: multiply; while setting the color of what's behind the image to either the R,G or B color?
Something like this:


.example-container-rgb {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.example-container-r {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.example-container-g {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0f0;
}

.example-container-b {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00f;
}
<div class="example-container-rgb">
      <img id="example-element" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" width="200" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;">
</div>
<div class="example-container-r">
      <img id="example-element" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" width="200" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;">
</div>
<div class="example-container-g">
      <img id="example-element" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" width="200" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;">
</div>
<div class="example-container-b">
      <img id="example-element" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" width="200" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply;">
</div>




This is similar to what I would like to achieve, but it only selects one channel. #RRGGBB becomes #RR0000. I would like to get #RRRRRR.

Do you think there is a way to duplicate the selected channel into the other two?

@AlbertoChiesa Sorry, I can't think of one. Perhaps you do need a canvas or SVG for this with some matrix algebra? See my simple attempt here: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/gbYMwob?editors=1010 which uses feColorMatrix

You can make a structure like this and use CSS:


.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;  /* Set to your image width */
  height: 480px;  /* Set to your image height */
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;  /* Ensures the image covers the container */
}

#red-channel {
  filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0) contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(0deg);
}

#green-channel {
  filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0) contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(120deg);
}

#blue-channel {
  filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0) contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(240deg);
}
<div class="image-container">
  <img id="original" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Camera Stream" />
  <img id="red-channel" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Red Channel" />
  <img id="green-channel" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Green Channel" />
  <img id="blue-channel" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Blue Channel" />
</div>




I tried your code and it seemed to just reduce everything to one color on each image. Could you make a runnable snippet which you've tested works, and also maybe a short explanation of why it works would be useful? Thanks.
